# Why Did God Directly Command Abraham to Sacrifice Isaac but Sent Angels to Stop Him?

Tags: abraham, binding-of-isaac

Genesis 21:1-3 says that God “tested” Abraham by commanding him to sacrifice his son Isaac and that Abraham immediately (or almost immediately) followed the directions God provided. 21:9-17 says that Abraham was just about to slaughter Isaac when an angel called out to him not to. A ram was provided as an alternative sacrifice. A second angel related to Abraham that it was a test from God which he passed with flying colors. Due to Abraham’s faith in God, his descendants will be a great nation through which all other nations will be blessed.

God himself commanded Abraham to sacrifice Isaac but He sent two angels to follow through with the other elements of the story. Did Abraham have any doubts when “only” an angel was sent to stop him from sacrificing Isaac? Why didn’t God Himself stop Abraham and, after doing so, why didn’t God inform Abraham his reward?

Note that there are two intertwined questions here. One involving Abraham’s faith only in God but he nevertheless listened to angels. The other being why God commanded Abraham directly but decided to send angels to follow up.

Comment: I feel like this has been asked here before

Comment: I know that I have addressed this exact subject in previous answers to related questions.

Comment: He didn't say to sacrifice he said to bring up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Leviticus Rabbah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leviticus_Rabbah) (parsha 1) states that the angel called but the utterance spoke:

> באברהם כתיב ויקרא מלאך ה' אל אברהם המלאך קורא והדבור מדבר

[R. Yaakov Tzvi Mecklenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Tzvi_Mecklenburg) understands this to mean that the angel only called out Abraham's name, but the actual rest of the command to desist was spoken by God Himself:

> נראה דעתם כי האמירה היתה מפי הקדוש ברוך הוא והמלאך לא קרא אלא את שם אברהם לעוררו אל שמיעת הדבור שיבא אליו מפי הקב"ה

[R. Samson Raphael Hirsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch) in his commentary explains that God had to give the original command to sacrifice Isaac, because had the command been given by an angel Abraham would not have believed it since it contradicted all his previous messages from God. But the command to desist from sacrificing Isaac was believable even from an angel because it realigned with all the previous messages:

> הלא דבר הוא שכאן שלח ה' את דברו ביד מלאך בעוד שבכל מקום אחר במשך חיי אברהם ה' בעצמו דיבר עם אברהם אכן כאן כדי לעצור את מילוי הציווי היה די בשליחת מלאך
>
> דבר זה שהוא יוצא מן הכלל מגלה לנו טפח מהמאבק הפנימי העמוק שאברהם נתנסה בו אילו
> מלאך היה מעמיד בפניו ציווי להקריב את בנו כקרבן לא היה אברהם מאמין לו הלא הסתירה בין ציווי זה לבין הגילויים שגילה לו ה' עד כה הן גילויים באופן כללי והן בנוגע ליצחק בפרט   צועקת עד לב השמים אך לשם חזרה מציווי העקידה היה די בשליחת מלאך לא היה נדרש כל גילוי יוצא מן הכלל כדי להבהיר את הסיבה לחזרה הזאת ולשם הסברת כל ציווי העקידה כנסיון המראה שהיות האדם מוכן לעמוד בנסיון שקולה כעמידה בו חזרה זו התאימה בהתאמה מלאה לכל דבר אחר שאברהם ידע על ה

[R. Meir Leibush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim) explains that it was specifically the angel that gave the command to desist because as the Sages say, every fulfillment of a commandment creates an angel. Thus, this was the angel that was created from the fulfillment of God's command which had already been fulfilled without actually slaughtering Isaac. But if Abraham would continue to slaughter Isaac it would turn the entire act into murder and the angel generated from the good deed would lose its existence. Thus, the angel had to jump in and tell Abraham to desist:

> הנה הדבור קח נא את בנך היה ע"י ה' בעצמו והקריאה אל תשלח היה ע"י מלאך ולמה לא עכבו ה' בעצמו הנה מלבד מה שיתבאר שהיה נסיון גם בזה  י"ל עפ"י מ"ש חז"ל שמכל מצוה יולד מלאך שליח ה' לגמלו טוב בעד המצוה ההיא כמ"ש שכר מצוה מצוה שהמצוה עצמה תגמלהו שכרו  והנה מצוה הגדולה הזאת נגמרה עתה בשלמות בכל פרטיה ונברא ממנה מלאך ה' אבל אם היה אברהם שוחט את יצחק אז היה נחשב כרוצח כי לא היה רצון ה' רק שיעלהו לא שישחטהו  וע"כ קרא אליו מלאך הזה בעצמו לעכבו מן המעשה שבה תלוי מציאותו וקיומו וע"כ אמר במד' שהמלאכים בכו כשרצה אברהם לשחוט את יצחק רצו שהמלאכים שנבראו מן המצוה הזאת שהיה בה כמה חלקים הקיחה וההליכה ובנין המזבח ועריכת העצים והעקדה והעליה על המזבח שמכ"א נברא מלאך וחיות המלאך וקיומו הוא מן המצוה הזאת ואם היה שוחט אותו היו כל המעשים הקודמים הכנה אל רצח ותועבת ה' וע"כ בכו מלאכים אלה כי יהיו כאין וכאפס  וז"ש לו כי עתה ידעתי כי ירא אלהים אתה ולא חשכת וכו' ממני שעורו כי עתה ידעתי ממני כי ירא אלהים אתה  שממני ר"ל מה שנבראתי מן המצוה הזאת ואני חי וקיים ידעתי כי עתה ירא אלהים אתה ולא חשכת את בנך ר"ל שעתה נגמרה המצוה שהיה תכליתה לידע שאתה ירא אלהים ולא חשכת את בנך וכ"ז ידעתי עתה והשחיטה היא למותר ויהי' רצח ותועבה

This could perhaps also explain why Abraham believed the angel — when he realized that the angel was already generated he knew that the commandment had already been fulfilled.

R. Shlomo Sofer records the following incident<sup>1</sup> towards the beginning of Chut Hameshulash (it doesn't seem to be in the earlier edition so there is an image from the 1978 edition below):

When [R. Elijah of Vilna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) signed the missive against [Chasidut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasidic_Judaism) his student [R. Zalman](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%96%27%D7%99%D7%9F) was approached to sign as well. R. Zalman responded by bringing up the question here, namely, how Abraham could heed the command of a mere angel to desist when the command to sacrifice Isaac was from God himself. R. Zalman explained that when it comes to slaughtering someone, only a direct command from God is sufficient to allow it. When it comes to saving someone, however, the directive of an angel suffices. Applying this to the situation at hand, R. Zalman concluded that even though R. Elijah was like an angel, to slaughter someone requires a direct command from God himself, so he was unable to follow his rebbe in this instance. And the story concludes with R. Elijah apparently agreeing to R. Zalman's argument.

[image: Image of page of Chut Hameshulash]

---

<sup>1. The full details of this incident may be subject to question, because R. Zalman's name is signed on the missive.</sup>

Comment: +1 R' Zalman means R' Shlomo Zalman Rappaport, author of Dvash HaSadeh?

Comment: @user6591 R. Shlomo Zalman brother of R. Chaim of Volozhin.

Comment: A bit coincidental then as far as numerous Rabbis named Shlomo Zalman saying this. The Maayana Shel Torah brings this same exact idea from Dvash Hasadeh. Perhaps this is more evidence to your speculative footnote.

Comment: @user6591 Interesting. Do you have a more precise source or link for that?

Comment: No sorry. In fact I'm just assuming Maayana Shel Torah means that Dvash Hasadeh and not a different one.

Comment: My Rebbe told me it was R Chaim Volozhin that refused to sign based on the above.

Comment: @DavidKenner Indeed, I have heard that suggested. (I didn't include it in the answer because it's kind of tangential.)

Comment: @alex, cool... I once wished we had rock solid sources for "stories". But as we see, its hard to come by. :)