# Identifying the author Toras Yekusiel

Tags: history, vilna-gaon, misnaged

I recently came across this teaching: [in footnote Aleph.]
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3751&st=&pgnum=11

To summarize: during the time when the Vilna Gaon made his cherem against chassidim, The author of Toras Yekusiel was approached to sign the ban but he refused explaining, based on the story of Akeidas Yitzchak, that only G-d himself can give a command to "slaughter" another Jew.

My question is twofold. Firstly who is the author of Toras Yekusiel, and secondly i'v heard he may have been a close disciple of the Gr"a. If so, is it possible he could have disagreed with his master about his attitude towards chassidim? (As evident from his teaching)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97027/why-did-god-directly-command-abraham-to-sacrifice-isaac-but-sent-angels-to-stop/97032#97032

Comment: Thanks, so their appears to be different versions of who was the student that didn't sign.

Answer (score 4):

http://hebrewbooks.org/8360

Author is Rabbi Refael Katz Zatzal